# Double Integral over region

Tags: integration

*Problem:*

Compute the double integral  $$\iint_R xsin(y^2) dA$$

over the region $$R { (x,y): 0≤x≤3   ,   x^2≤y≤9 } $$

Determine in which order it would be possible to perform the integration and compute it this way.

---

*What I have so far:*

I think that my bounds for this double integral are $$ \int_{x^2}^9 \int_{0}^3 $$ by using region $R$ as my guide. This implies that I would be integrating with respect to $x$ first, because integrating with respect to $y$ first yields a nasty integral computation. Therefore, my iterated integral would be

$$ \int_{x^2}^9 \int_{0}^3 xsin(y^2) dxdy $$

If this truly is the easier order to solve, how do I start? Either way, I will have to compute the integral of $sin(y^2)$ at some point. I have lots of questions in regards to this question but I think it would help more to be guided through this type of problem.

Comment: If the bounds for $y$ is given in terms of $x$ then you HAVE TO integrate with respect to $y$ first. It's possible to switch order of integration, but it's not as easy as switching the bounds.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:**

You must change the bounds of integration. You want that $\int_{0}^{3}\; \int_{x^2}^{9}\; f(x,y)\; dy\; dx = \int_{0}^{9}\; \int_{0}^{\sqrt{y}}\; f(x,y)\; dx\; dy$.

By Fubini's Theorem, we change this integral into a much more tractable form.

**Answer:**

For point of exposition, I write the solution.

We evaluate $\int_{0}^{9}\; \int_{0}^{\sqrt{y}}\; x \sin(y^2)\; dx\; dy \\
= \int_{0}^{9}\; y/2 \sin(y^2)\; dy \\
= 1/4 [-\cos(81)+\cos(0)] \\
= 1/2 \sin^2(81/2).$

It is important to recall that we are evaluating this in radians.

Comment: @Gahawar, it has happened to the best of us.

Comment: When you say change the bounds of integration, I get that you flip the order of integration(from dxdy to dydx), but the new bounds are unclear to me. Why do you change them the way that you do?

Comment: @Xing, suppose we fix $y$. Then what are the bounds on $x$? Well, $x^2 \leq y$ and $x \geq 0$. So, $0 \leq x \leq \sqrt{y}$. Now what are the bounds on $y$? Well, $0 \leq x^2 \leq y \leq 9$ and since $x$ could equal zero, $0 \leq y \leq 9$. This is probably best seen graphically where you fix a horizontal line and put in place your upper and lower bounds of x in terms of y.

Comment: OK, I understand now, but I still am unable to compute the integral $sin(y^2)$

Comment: @DavidCardinal, I've amended the answer. Hopefully this helps.